# Initialize the array into while recent post woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Initialize the array into while recent post woocommerce?

When I want to display the latest product

I want to put in an array and show them in one section

only 9 post Initialize.

correct?

```
<?php
$arry = array("", "", "","", "", "","", "", "");
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 5,'post_type' => 'product'); 
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params); 
?>
<?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $i =0 ; while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php $array[$i] = the_title(); ?>

<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Does this help?

I prefer to change the `array()` to shorthand: `[]`.

```
<?php
$arry = array();
$params = array('posts_per_page' => 9,'post_type' => 'product'); 
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params); 
?>
<?php if ($wc_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $i =0 ; while ($wc_query->have_posts()) : $wc_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php $array[$i] = array( 'index'=>$i,'title'=>the_title(),'content'=>the_content(),'permalink'=>the_permalink() ); ?>

<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if(!empty($array)){
    foreach ($array as $post) {
        echo '<h2>'.$post['title'].'</h2>';
        echo '<p>'.$post['content'].'</p>';
    }
}?>
```